# How can I get the dict whose specific key is maximum in a dict of dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, max

Say I have a dictionary with max and min temperatures of every month:

```
t = {
    'jan': {
        'max': 21,
        'min': 12
    },
    'feb': {
        'max': 18,
        'min': 15
    },
    'mar': {
        'max': 20,
        'min': 17
    }
}
```

Now I want to know which month has the biggest `max` value. For this example, I would like to get this dict as a result (since 21 > 18 in Feb, and 21 > 20 in Mar):

```
'jan': {
    'max': 21,
    'min': 12
}
```

I can get what is the biggest dictionary easily with [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> max(t.values(), key=lambda s: s.get('max'))
{'max': 21, 'min': 12}
```

However, it is important to me to get the dict's key as well, so instead of just `{'max': 21, 'min': 12}` I want the full `'jan': {'max':21, 'min':12}`.

The current approach I use is a basic loop checking for the values:

```
max_dict = dict()
max_key = ''
for k, v in t.items(): 
    if max_dict.get('max',0) <= v.get('max', 0): 
        max_dict = v 
        max_key = k
```

And now `max_key` contains "jan", while `max_dict` contains `{'max': 21, 'min': 12}`.

However, I guess some kind of sorting with max can provide the result in a more straight-forward way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the max of `t.items()` with an appropriate key:

```python
>>> max(t.items(), key=lambda s: s[1]['max'])
('jan', {'max': 21, 'min': 12})
```

Comment: Good one, by using the tuple coming from `t.items()`